# mySQL moving rows from 2 tables to other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, inner-join

hello i can't seem to figure out why this sql statement doesn't work?

i am trying to move rows from table1 and table2 into table3 and table4. i thought the easiest approach to this was by selecting the rows with inner join and then making 2 INSERT INTO.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table3 (id, content, createdBy, createdDate, endTime, startTime) 
VALUES (table1.id, table1.content, table1.createdBy, table1.createdDate, table1.endTime, table1.startTime);
INSERT INTO table4 (table3_Id, sometableid) 
VALUES (table2.table3_Id, table2.sometableid);
SELECT table1.id, 
table1.content, 
table1.createdBy, 
table1.createdDate, 
table1.endTime, 
table1.startTime, 
table2.table2_id, 
table2.sometableid
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
WHERE table1.endTime < NOW()
COMMIT;
```

when i run this sql it outputs #1054 - Unknown column 'table1.id' in 'field list'

if anyone has any good ideas, or can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (id, content, createdBy, createdDate, endTime, startTime)
SELECT id, content, createdBy, createdDate, endTime, startTime
FROM table1
WHERE endTime < NOW();

INSERT INTO table4 (table3_Id, sometableid)
SELECT t2.table2_id, t2.sometableid
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
WHERE t1.endTime < NOW();
```